# Android - Playing the “call is connecting” sound in the inner speaker

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an application which is a dialer for making VOIP calls.

I'm not sure how to play the "ringing" sound when the user is making an outgoing call. I know how to play the ringtone for incoming calls by creating a MediaPlayer object, but not sure how to play that specific sound and how to play it only on the inner speakers so the user knows the call is waiting to connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How can I play the “call is ringing” sound in the inner speaker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969486/android-how-can-i-play-the-call-is-ringing-sound-in-the-inner-speaker)

Comment: It _was_ a duplicate to a question you posted earlier, which you deleted shortly thereafter. This is at least the fourth time you've posted this question and deleted the previous version. You need to stop doing that. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: It seems like it wasn't a duplicate. If you know of an answer to that question or a link you might have seen which confused you to think this was a duplicate, please give a link to that question as it can help the community.

Comment: I already gave a link to your previous question in my first comment. Some people might not be able to see the question since you deleted it, but users with sufficient reputation are allowed to see deleted questions. And whether or not anyone answered it is irrelevant. Deleting your question and then immediately re-posting it just to draw more attention is wrong. What you should do is try to improve the original question by editing in additional information that would make it more likely that someone can answer it.

Comment: so you say you are not going to help the community, but only comment. I see..